# Caesar cipher on Swift error with decrypt

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I make an application for the report on the subject of system security. [Caesar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)'s swift code. and I ran into a problem when in decrypting phase.

When I enter the key, the program randomly knocks out the error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Or an array exit error

I'm a newbie. Please explain to me how I can fix this error and make my program work properly.

Google didn't help me.

```
import UIKit

class CaesarCipher: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var messageText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cipherTextLabel: UILabel!

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @IBOutlet weak var cryptMessageText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cryptKeyText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var decryptTextLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func cipherButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if (messageText.text == "") || (keyText.text == "")
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ошибка", message: "Одно, или несколько полей пустые", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ок", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            let key = keyText.text
            let e: Int32 = Int32.init(key!)!
            //let upKey: Int32 = Int32.init(&e)

            let messageCipher = messageText.text
            // var i: Int8 = Int8.init(messageCipher!)!
            //let up: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.init(&i)

            //cipherTextLabel = encrypt(up, e)
            let encryptText = cipher(messageCipher!, shift: Int(e))
            cipherTextLabel.text = "\(encryptText)"
        } 
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @IBAction func decryptButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if (cryptMessageText.text == "") || (cryptKeyText.text == "")
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ошибка", message: "Одно, или несколько полей пустые", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ок", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            let cryptKey = cryptKeyText.text
            let e: Int = Int.init(cryptKey!)!
            //let upKey: Int32 = Int32.init(&e)

            let decryptMessageText = cryptMessageText.text
            // var i: Int8 = Int8.init(messageCipher!)!
            //let up: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.init(&i)

            //cipherTextLabel = encrypt(up, e)
            let decryptText = decipher(decryptMessageText!, shift2: Int(e))
            decryptTextLabel.text = "\(decryptText)"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboard()
    }
}

func cipher( _ text:String, shift:Int ) -> String {

    var textCharArray:[Character] = Array( text.characters )

    let alphabet = Array("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ !".characters);

    let offset = alphabet.count // alphabet.length in other languages

    for i in 0 ..< text.characters.count {

        let oldChar = textCharArray[ i ]
        let oldCharIdx = alphabet.index( of:oldChar ) // get index of

        let oldCharIdxUnwrapped = oldCharIdx // oldCharIdx can be null!
        let newCharIdx = ( oldCharIdxUnwrapped! + shift + offset ) % offset

        let newChar = alphabet[ newCharIdx ]

        textCharArray[ i ] = newChar
    }

    return String( textCharArray )
}

func decipher( _ text:String, shift2:Int ) -> String {

    // when calling a function you don't have to specify the first argument...
    // For other arguments you have to specify it!
    return cipher( text, shift:shift2 * -1 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see usually gets thrown when there is an Optional (a value that could be nil) and you try to unwrap it (using '!').

> Swift also introduces optional types, which handle the absence of a
>   value. Optionals say either “there is a value, and it equals x” or
>   “there isn’t a value at all”.

That being said, the problem here is that UITextfields when "empty" might have nil for their text property. so when you do

```
    let key = keyText.text
    let e: Int32 = Int32.init(key!)!
```

`key` could be a nil value. And `(nil)!` will result in `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

To fix this, I suggest you add a nil check for your UITextfield's text property or
change your `if else` block to the following

```
    if let key = keyText.text, let messageCipher = messageText.text, !key.isEmpty, !messageCipher.isEmpty {
        // key and messageCipher are neither nil nor empty.
    } else {
        // keyText.text or messageText.text are either nil or empty
    }
```

If you are interested in swift programming and making apps for iOS, I suggest you look up more on how swift deals with `optional`s, and implicitly unwrapped optionals. A place to start would be https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html and follow up with tutorials.